# What platform / tool / software / language should i use for text mining?

Tags: hadoop, weka, similarity, mahout, text-mining

I am a begineer to the field of text mining . 
I need to perform work on the document similarity .I aim at comparing two documents and then providing the similarity between them in terms of a number. I have  read a lot of theory about this . I am planning to start with the cosine similarity

Can any of you help me with these basics questions : 
1. What platform ? (windows/linux)
2. What tool (People talk about weka / mahout / hadoop ) - i have no idea on what to use 
3. What language ? 
Some questions might sound absurd , but i have to start from scratch and i need some help

Comment: The query is way too broad. Do some research and then ask questions in the forums.

Comment: I just wanted some suggestions..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For software, I highly recommend RapidMiner, which you can grab from http://rapid-i.com. Some quick pros:

- Open source and implemented in Java (works on any platform)
- Intuitive graphical "operator pipeline" for hundreds of data mining tasks
- Excellent text mining support. See this [video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TyZjom46yGA)

In my experience data mining requires some real discipline to achieve desirable results. RapidMiner should help.

Comment: Thank you .. But wat do u think about the weka tools ? is it effective ?

Comment: Here's a discussion on RM vs Weka: http://rapid-i.com/rapidforum/index.php?topic=501.0. It does not appear to be biased. Never used Weka, but i do know RM has Weka plugins..

Answer (score 1):

Document similarity, as in the context of **text search**? Then [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) will fit the bill. It is a open source enterprise search platform with all features necessary for text search, including '**more like this**', which can fetch n documents which are textually similar.

A couple relavent features that may interest you:

1. it can be easily deployed as a Java web app on Tomcat, if Hadoop setup intimidates you.
2. facets and numerical comparisons which can augment text comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

Platform - Linux (mostly preferred)

Tool - Open NLP , Lucene , Solr(Text-Search) , Mahout , Matlab TMG( Not for advance level)

Language - R ( I will prefer ), Python+SciPy